# htaccess one RewriteCond for multiple RewriteRules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have trouble with redirects in .htaccess.
I have several domains (example.com, example.net, example.uk). I have set of RewriteRules for each domain. But for some reason, the redirects works for all domains. Following is my tried htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com|example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^1example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^2example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^3example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^4example$ /example4  [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.net|example\.net) [NC]
RewriteRule ^5example$ /sgsg  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^6example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^7example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^8example$ /example44  [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.uk|example\.uk) [NC]
RewriteRule ^9example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^10example$ /example12  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^11example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^12example$ /example41  [R=302,L]
```

Do you have any idea how to separate RewriteRules only for specific domain?

Comment: `RewriteCond` is applied to next immediate `RewriteRule` only.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts; please try following .htaccess rules file. As per anubhava's comments have added `RewriteCond` conditions before each `RewriteRule`.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:1|3)example$ /  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(2|4)example$ /example$1  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^5example$ /sgsg  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^6example$ /example2  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^7example$ /  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^8example$ /example44  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^9example$ /  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^10example$ /example12  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^11example$ /  [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^12example$ /example41  [R=302,L,NC]
```

***Fixes applied to OP's attempts:***

- Attached 2 rules into 1 eg: `RewriteRule ^(?:1|3)example$ /  [R=302,L,NC]` very first rule in above file.
- Added `NC` flag in both `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in all of the rules.
- Made use of non-capturing group in `RewriteCond` to make `www.` optional eg: FROM `^(www\.example\.com|example\.com)` TO `^(?:www\.)?example\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive itself applies only to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. The `RewriteCond` directive forms part of a single rule.

However, you can "workaround" this in various ways, without having to apply the same *condition* to multiple rules.

For example:

```
# Skip the following 4 rules when host is NOT "example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=4]

# These rules only apply to "example.com"
RewriteRule ^1example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^2example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^3example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^4example$ /example4  [R=302,L]

# Skip the following 4 rules when host is NOT "example.net"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=4]

# These rules only apply to "example.net"
RewriteRule ^5example$ /sgsg  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^6example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^7example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^8example$ /example44  [R=302,L]

# Skip the following 4 rules when host is NOT "example.uk"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=4]

# These rules only apply to "example.uk"
RewriteRule ^9example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^10example$ /example12  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^11example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^12example$ /example41  [R=302,L]
```

---

Alternatively, you could temporarily prefix the hostname to the URL-path and test for this directly in the `RewriteRule` directive.

For example:

```
# Prefix the hostname to the URL-path
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com|example\.net|example\.uk)
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^example\.com/1example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.com/2example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.com/3example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.com/4example$ /example4  [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^example\.net/5example$ /sgsg  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.net/6example$ /example2  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.net/7example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.net/8example$ /example44  [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^example\.uk/9example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.uk/10example$ /example12  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.uk/11example$ /  [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^example\.uk/12example$ /example41  [R=302,L]

# (OPTIONAL) Remove hostname prefix from URL-path
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*) $1
```