# .htaccess 301 redirect whole URL including Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I need to redirect around 300 URLs on a multidomain site that has the same URL structure on the different domains. For example:

`https://www.example.com/de/products.html` needs to be redirected to `https://www.example.org/de/products.html`

So my usual approach does not work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /de/products.html$ /de/products.html
```

I would need something like

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://www.example.com/de/products.html$ https://www.example.org/de/products.html
```

which obviously doesn't work or I just didn't get to work.

Not sure if important, but it's a TYPO3 instance.

Comment: RedirectMatch matches against the path component of the URL only. You'll need to use mod_rewrite for this - a RewriteCond to check the host name, followed by a RewriteRule that matches the path and does the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive matches against the URL-path only. To match the hostname you'll need to use mod_rewrite with an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (the value of the `Host` HTTP request header).

Also, since the URL structure is the same on both domains then you only need a single rule - just use the same URL-path from the initial request. No need to do one-by-one redirects as you seem to be trying to do.

For example, the following would need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file *before* any existing rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything from example.com to example.org and preserve the URL-path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This checks for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable already contains a slash prefix, hence it is omitted in the *substitution* string.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

**UPDATE:**

> But I don't want to redirect all URLs, just some.

To redirect a specific URL to the same URL at the target domain, as per your original example:

```
# Redirect "/de/product.html" only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^de/products\.html$ https://www.example.org/$0 [R=301,L]
```

The above redirects `https://www.example.com/de/products.html` only to `https://www.example.org/de/products.html`.

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against.

> How to extend your snippet with `/de/` or `/fr/` etc.? For example I want to redirect `example.com/de/products.html` but not `example.com/products.html`

Maybe the above example is what you require. Alternatively, to redirect `/de/<something>` (or `/fr/<something>`) only and not just `/<something>`, you could do something like this:

```
# Redirect "/<lang>/<something>" only, where <lang> is "de" or "fr"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(de|fr)/[^/]+$ https://www.example.org/$0 [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect `https://example.com/de/<something>` to `https://www.example.org/de/<something>`.

Comment: But I don't want to redirect all URLs, just some. How to extend your snippet with /de/ or /fr/ etc.?

Comment: For example I want to redirect https://www.example.com/de/products.html but not https://www.example.com/products.html

Comment: @lufi I've updated my answer with a couple of suggestions. Note that depending on the specific URLs you are redirecting, you could perhaps structure the redirect directives in a more optimal/compact way. For example, you could avoid having to use the same _condition_ (that checks the hostname) on multiple rules. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72134517/369434) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125742/htaccess-one-rewritecond-for-multiple-rewriterules) for some ideas in this regard.